# Jenkins pipeline checkout wrong revision

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to implement a new Jenkins pipeline using Jenkinsfile.

**The GIT repository does not have a Jenkinsfile on every branch, just under a specific one (as I'm currently building CI stuff for a legacy repository).**

Jenkins Pipeline is created with following configuration:

- Discard old builds (I don't want to manually cleanup)
- Bitbucket webhook trigger (on push event)
- Pipeline script from SCM

  - Bitbucket server (using Bitbucket server plugin)
  - Authentication stuff
  - Branches to build: `**`
  - Script path: `Jenkinsfile`
  - Lightweight checkout is disabled

The webhook is automatically created in my Bitbucket repository, and builds are triggered just fine (when I push modification on the branch with the `Jenkinsfile`).

However, Jenkins does not checkout the commit sent in the hook (different HASH from another branch). As a result, build crashes as `Jenkinsfiles` do not exist on another branches (and will never exist on old legacy branches).

```
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- http://mybitbucket:port/scm/vs/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/myrepo/* # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository myrepo/old-branch-a
Seen branch in repository myrepo/old-branch-b
...
Seen 40 remote branches
 > git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0a781a1bd4ad194aae911ce26d1ec4cd1e73dd76 (myrepo/old-branch-x)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0a781a1bd4ad194aae911ce26d1ec4cd1e73dd76 # timeout=10
Commit message: "my commit message"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Posting build status of INPROGRESS to mybitbucket for commit id [0a781a1bd4ad194aae911ce26d1ec4cd1e73dd76] and ref 'null'
ERROR: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/myrepo@script/Jenkinsfile not found
```

Technical context:

- Jenkins 2.303.3 running in a docker container
- [Bitbucket server integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/) plugin

I cannot understand why this revision is chosen over the one sent in the hook.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Git seems to be behaving correctly: Jenkins is telling it to do a detached-HEAD checkout of the specified commit hash ID, and it does. So this is entirely a Jenkins issue: why is Jenkins specifying that particular hash ID? (I don't know the answer: Jenkins is often mysterious.)

Comment: Does "_does not checkout the commit sent in the hook (different HASH from another branch)_" mean that the commit ID sent in the hook is from another branch than those who contains the `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: The commit HASH sent in the hook (visible from Bitbucket interface) is the right one (i.e the one from the branch that contains the `Jenkinsfile`). As far as I understand, Bitbucket is doing its part correctly.

Comment: HI @DavidL Since you are saying the changes made were on the same branch as the Jenkinsfile, can you see if you can trigger it manually (w/o making any other changes to the branch) and see if the exact commit hash is reflecting in the jenkins log ? This helps to see if the Jenkins has received the commit info from BitBucket or not. 
If it does receive the latest commit info now, then must have been some n/w glitch that prevented the commit info to reach Jenkins and you may then try with new commits this time.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I've try to trigger the pipeline using Postman, and the result is the same: some out of space revision is checkout regardless of the HASH from the body of my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was misled all along.

Turn out that I need to use `Multibranch pipelines` instead of regular ones. It works well and create webhooks automatically as desired (using the right `Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers` configuration).

I'm still frustrated by the behaviour of regular pipelines, which makes no sense to me and seems poorly documented.